Vercel Deployment error : Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
This is the entire build logs for reference :
[13:26:30.300] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[13:26:30.513] Cloning github.com/shubh-2309/Pantry-Tracker (Branch: main, Commit: 28fd028)
[13:26:30.554] Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
[13:26:30.932] Cloning completed: 415.437ms
[13:26:31.566] Running "vercel build"
[13:26:32.601] Vercel CLI 35.2.3
[13:26:33.321] Installing dependencies...
[13:26:40.758] npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer      supported
[13:26:41.481] npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
[13:26:43.923] npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
[13:26:44.018] npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
[13:26:44.670] npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
[13:26:59.299] 
[13:26:59.300] added 465 packages in 26s
[13:26:59.300] 
[13:26:59.301] 137 packages are looking for funding
[13:26:59.301]   run `npm fund` for details
[13:26:59.303] npm notice
[13:26:59.303] npm notice New patch version of npm available! 10.8.1 -> 10.8.2
[13:26:59.303] npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.2
[13:26:59.303] npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.2
[13:26:59.303] npm notice
[13:26:59.329] Detected Next.js version: 14.2.5
[13:26:59.342] Running "npm run build"
[13:26:59.494] 
[13:26:59.494] > pantry_tracker@0.1.0 build
[13:26:59.494] > next build
[13:26:59.494] 
[13:27:00.589] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[13:27:00.594] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[13:27:00.599] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[13:27:00.599] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[13:27:00.602] 
[13:27:00.747]   ▲ Next.js 14.2.5
[13:27:00.747] 
[13:27:00.923]    Creating an optimized production build ...
[13:27:21.837]  ✓ Compiled successfully
[13:27:21.838]    Linting and checking validity of types ...
[13:27:23.485]    Collecting page data ...
[13:27:24.501]    Generating static pages (0/5) ...
[13:27:25.769]    Generating static pages (1/5) 
[13:27:25.770]    Generating static pages (2/5) 
[13:27:25.991]    Generating static pages (3/5) 
[13:27:26.253] [2024-08-09T07:57:26.203Z]  @firebase/analytics: Analytics: Firebase Analytics is not supported in this environment. Wrap initialization of analytics in analytics.isSupported() to prevent initialization in unsupported environments. Details: (1) Cookies are not available. (analytics/invalid-analytics-context).
[13:27:26.254] ReferenceError: window is not defined
[13:27:26.254]     at l7 (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:629:550)
[13:27:26.258]     at u_ (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:674:922)
[13:27:26.259]     at aV.instanceFactory (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:674:1644)
[13:27:26.259]     at aq.getOrInitializeService (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:239:2777)
[13:27:26.259]     at aq.initialize (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:239:2152)
[13:27:26.259]     at uA (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:674:1286)
[13:27:26.259]     at uR (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:674:1119)
[13:27:26.260]     at 5654 (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:2874:321)
[13:27:26.260]     at Object.t [as require] (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
[13:27:26.260]     at require (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:18490) {
[13:27:26.260]   digest: '2218002914'
[13:27:26.260] }
[13:27:26.261] 
[13:27:26.261] Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[13:27:26.261] 
[13:27:26.262] ReferenceError: window is not defined
[13:27:26.262]     at l7 (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:629:550)
[13:27:26.262]     at u_ (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:674:922)
[13:27:26.262]     at aV.instanceFactory (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:674:1644)
[13:27:26.262]     at aq.getOrInitializeService (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:239:2777)
[13:27:26.262]     at aq.initialize (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:239:2152)
[13:27:26.263]     at uA (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:674:1286)
[13:27:26.263]     at uR (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:674:1119)
[13:27:26.263]     at 5654 (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/app/page.js:2874:321)
[13:27:26.263]     at Object.t [as require] (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
[13:27:26.263]     at require (/vercel/path0/pantry_tracker/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:18490)
[13:27:26.266] 
[13:27:26.266] > Export encountered errors on following paths:
[13:27:26.266]  /page: /
[13:27:26.267]  ✓ Generating static pages (5/5)
[13:27:26.301] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[13:27:27.067] 

I tried CI = false in the env variables and also overrid the build command to npm run build. Still getting this error
